# How do I code a basic flip flop in Verilog Pro?

Tags: verilog

I tried to code a basic flip flop using NAND gates in Verilog Pro, but the waveform I'm getting is not correct. Please see what's wrong with it.

```
//design module
module rstt(s,r,q,qbar);
input r,s;
output q,qbar;
nand n1(q,r,qbar);
nand n2(qbar,s,q);
endmodule

//stimulus module 
module test;
reg r,s;
wire q,qbar;
initial begin
r=1'b1;
s=1'b0;
#25 r=1'b0;
  s=1'b1;
#25 r=1'b1;
  s=1'b1;
#100 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Plot of the waveform and a description of what's wrong, please...

Comment: i m getting straight lines in q and qbar. n getting no lines in s and r. these are wrong waves for basic flip flop using nand gates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not instantiate your `rstt` module inside your `test` module.  This means that the wires (`q` and `qbar`) inside module `test` are undriven.  That is why they remain as straight lines instead of toggling.  According to the IEEE Verilog standard, a undriven `wire` will default to `1'bz`.

Try something like this:

```
//design module
module rstt(s,r,q,qbar);
input r,s;
output q,qbar;
nand n1(q,r,qbar);
nand n2(qbar,s,q);
endmodule

//stimulus module 
module test;
reg r,s;
wire q,qbar;

rstt i0 (
    .s    (s),
    .r    (r),
    .q    (q),
    .qbar (qbar)
);

initial begin
r=1'b1;
s=1'b0;
#25 r=1'b0;
  s=1'b1;
#25 r=1'b1;
  s=1'b1;
#100 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Note that your problem is not specific to any simulator.